# Linux kernel version

Tags: kernel, linux-headers

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 (with extended life support).

This OS is using linux-image (or headers, or modules, or tools) version 4.15.0-50.

But... With Synaptic Packages Manager we can download and install the version 5.0.n-nn

Is it a good idea to do this?

Is there some compatibility problem if we do this?

Answer (score 0):

We can consider installing packages from official repositories as safe, they should work out of the box.

Just try it, installing the new kernel will not remove your current kernel. If the newer kernel doesn't work for you, you can easily boot the older kernel via Grub's boot menu and remove the new one, there is really no harm in doing that.

Remind that there are `generic` and `low-latency` kernels, for Ubuntu Studio you should choose the low-latency kernel.

---

I just installed the low-latency kernel version 5.0.0-15 in Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 and it seems to run fine. To install the kernel correctly you have to install 4 packages:

```
linux-headers-5.0.0-15
linux-modules-5.0.0-15-lowlatency
linux-image-5.0.0-15-lowlatency
linux-headers-5.0.0-15-lowlatency
```

My first impression is pretty good, programs open faster and the system appears a bit more responsive, I'll keep the new kernel...

Comment: I will try. Stay in tune!

Comment: I downloaded and installed this but... I don't see any noticeable difference in my system. Even more, when I use the command: `dpkg -l | grep linux-image (or headers, or modules, or tools, or source)` I can see the last `4.15.0-50-lowlatency` version, and the new `5.0.0-15-lowlatency` version, but... The final output line of this command is the version `4.15.0-50-lowlatency`. So... I suspect that the new version is not working, or... it cannot work here. I'm not sure.

Comment: Check with `uname -a` which kernel version is running. For me  the kernel is fine. We have different hardware, so you may feel no difference but I do (the difference is small though). The new kernel has a lot of improvements and new features https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-2019-features&num=1 . If you like it, keep it. If you don't like it, remove it. Decision is always yours.

Comment: Yes! I did it and now I know it is working with the last kernel (5.0.0-15-lowlatency).